# Django browser cache with static files

Tags: django, caching

According to Google Pagespeed hints, I should activate a Browser Cache for static files of my Django application.

I've read the Django docs but I don't understand if I must change any Django settings or only Apache settings to obtain the "max-age" (or others) header on page request from server.

I don't need memcached or any database caching, I just need only "Browser Cache" for static files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since Django doesn't serve static files in production, why would you need to change any Django settings?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Ok, maybe I have posted one stupid question. I have found the solution. I need to set the right informations of my web server which serves the static files.

Comment: But that's the point, Django does *not* do any of that for static files. It's all entirely up to the static server.

Comment: @ Fabrizio A  Even I am facing the same issue. What is the solution.